# Trigonometry of a 3D "free" camera

Tags: java, 3d, camera, trigonometry

I'm sorry if this question was asked before, I did search, and I did not find an answer.

My problem is, that I'd like to make movement on all 3 axes with the X and Y rotation of the camera being relevant.

This is what I did:

```
private static void fly(int addX, int addY){ //parameters are the direction change relative to the current rotation

    float angleX = rotation.x + addX;   //angle is basically the direction, into which we will be moving(when moving forward this is always the same as our actual rotation, therefore addX and addY would be 0, 0)
    float angleY = rotation.y + addY;


    float speed = (moveSpeed * 0.0002f) * delta;
    float hypotenuse = speed; //the length that is SUPPOSED TO BE moved overall on all 3 axes


    /* Y-Z side*/
    //Hypotenuse, Adjacent and Opposite side lengths of a triangle on the Y-Z side
    //The point where the Hypotenuse and the Adjacent meet is where the player currently is.
    //OppYZ is the opposite of this triangle, which is the ammount that should be moved on the Y axis.
    //the Adjacent is not used, don't get confused by it. I just put it there, so it looks nicer.
    float HypYZ = speed;
    float AdjYZ = (float) (HypYZ * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angleX))); //adjacent is on the Z axis
    float OppYZ = (float) (HypYZ * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angleX))); //opposite is on the Y axis

    /* X-Z side*/
    //Side lengths of a triangle on the Y-Z side
    //The point where the Hypotenuse and the Adjacent meet is where the player currently is.
    float HypXZ = speed;
    float AdjXZ = (float) (HypXZ * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angleY)));  //on X
    float OppXZ = (float) (HypXZ * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angleY)));  //on Z

    position.x += AdjXZ;
    position.y += OppYZ;
    position.z += OppXZ;
}
```

I only implement this method when moving forwards(parameters: 0, 90) or backwards(params: 180, 270), since movement can't happen on the Y axis while going sideways, since you don't rotate on the Z axis. ( the method for going sideways(strafing) works just fine, so I won't add that.)

**the problem is that when I look 90 degrees up or -90 down and then move forward I should be moving only on the Y axis(vertically) but for some reason I also move forwards(which means on the Z axis, as the X axis is the strafing).**

*I do realize that movement speed this way is not constant. If you have a solution for that, I'd gladly accept it as well.*

Comment: This is confusing. You're in 3D but you can only move/rotate in 2D? Doesn't that mean you're really just in 2D?

Comment: No. You CAN move in 3D with this code, but there is some logic error in it that results in unexpected behavior.
However it is correct that you can only rotate the camera in two axes, but rotating it on the Z axis is unusual.(that's like laying your head on your shoulder)
However, your position does change in all 3 directions, as you can see at the last 3 lines.
Or did I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your error lies in the fact that you **don't fully project your distance** (your quantity of movement `hypothenuse`) on your horizontal plane and vertical one.

In other words, whatever the chosen direction, what you are doing right now is moving your point of `hypothenuse` in the horizontal plane X-Z, even though you already move it of a portion of `hypothenuse` in the vertical direction Y.

What you probably want to do is moving your point of a `hypothenuse` quantity as a total.

So you have to evaluate how much of the movement takes place in the horizontal plane and how much in the vertical axis. Your direction gives you the answer.

Now, it is not clear to me right now what your 2 angles represent. I highly recommend you to use [Tait–Bryan angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Tait.E2.80.93Bryan_angles) in this situation (using only *yawn* and *pitch*, since you don't seem to need the *rolling* - what you call the Z-rotation), to simplify the calculations.

In this configuration, the yawn angle would be apparently similar to your definition of your `angleY`, while the pitch angle would be the angle between the horizontal plane and your `hypothenuse` vector (and not the angle of the projection in the plane Y-Z).

A schema to clarify:

[image: Evaluation of the displacement given two angles]

With :

- `s` your quantity of movement from your initial position `P_0` to `P_1` (`hypothenuse`)
- `a_y` the yawn angle and `a_p` the pitch one
- `D_x`, `D_y`, `D_z` the displacements for each axis (to be added to `position`, ie `AdjXZ`, `OppYZ` and `OppXZ`)

So if you look at this representation, you can see that your triangle in X-Z doesn't have `s` as hypotenuse but its projection `s_xz`. The evaluation of this distance is quite straightforward: if you place yourself in the triangle `P_0` `P_1` `P_1xz`, you can see that `s_xz = s * cos(a_p)`. Which gives you:

```
float HypXZ = speed * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angleP))); // s_xz
float AdjXZ = (float) (HypXZ * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angleY)));  // D_x
float OppXZ = (float) (HypXZ * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angleY)));  // D_z
```

As for `D_y` ie `OppYZ`, place yourself in the triangle `P_0` `P_1` `P_1xz` again, and you'll obtain:

```
float OppYZ = (float) (speed * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angleP))); // D_y
```

Now, if by `angleX` you actually meant the angle of *elevation* as I suppose you did, then `angleP = angleX` and `HypXZ = AdjYZ` in your code.

With this correction, if `angleX = 90` or `angleX = -90`, then

```
HypXZ = speed * cos(angleX) = speed * cos(90deg) = speed * 0;
```

... and thus `AdjXZ = 0` and `OppXZ = 0`. No movement in the horizontal plane.

---

Note:

To check if your calculations are correct, you can verify if you actually move your point of the wanted quantity of movement (`hypothenuse` ie `speed` ie `s`). Using Pythagorean theorem:

```
s² = s_xz² + D_z² // Applied in the triangle P_0 P_1 P_1xz
   = D_x² + D_y² + D_z² // Applied in the triangle P_0 P_1x P_1xz
```

With the definitions of the displacements given above:

```
D_x² + D_y² + D_z²
   = (s * cos(a_p) * cos(a_y))² + (s * cos(a_p) * sin(a_y))² + (s * sin(a_p))²
   = s² * (cos(a_p)² * cos(a_y)² + cos(a_p)² * sin(a_y)² + sin(a_p)²)
   = s² * (cos(a_p)² * (cos(a_y)² + sin(a_y)²) + sin(a_p)²)
   = s² * (cos(a_p)² * 1 + sin(a_p)²)
   = s² * (cos(a_p)² + sin(a_p)²)
   = s² * 1 // Correct
```

Hope it helped... Bye!

Comment: All I can say is Wow!! Thank you very much for this very detailed answer, I understand what I did wrong, and now it works! Thank you so much for your time and effort it took you to write this beautiful answer! :D You are the Man, good sir!